# Rails environments deployment (dev/test and production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

How do I go about setting up my dev/test/production apps with respect to folder locations on my web host?

I currently have two folders: MyDomainDev and MyDomainPro (for dev/test and production).

I have the subdomain "dev.mydomain.com" point to the dev/test folder and "mydomain.com" pointing to the production folder.  Is this correct or am I missing something fundamental with regards to dev/test/production environments?

Should there be really only one folder but that the environment is set by the presence of a subdomain in the url?

i.e., "mydomain.com" sets environment to be 'production' whereas "dev|test.mydomain.com" sets environment to be 'dev|test'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's probably not a great idea to have them on one server.  Probably OK if you're just getting started.

But that said, you can have one folder, but specify the environment to run in the Rack setup for each domain.  What server environment are you using?

Comment: I'm on a bluehost shared server.  Why is it a bad idea to have them on the same server?  I should clarify my context to say that there really is only one developer (me) and it isn't a super-traffic-heavy site.  An average of 60 visitors/day.

Comment: Well it seems I'm forced to use two separate directories - one for development and the other for production.  Do you have any idea why they might have done it that way?  Should I just create a symbolic link for the production folder to the dev folder or do you think that would break something?